# How can I get the functionality of `<input type="file" of HTML in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

How can I get the functionality of `<input type="file">` of HTML in Java Swing?

Answer (score 7):

See the docs: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html